# How to use the URL http://localhost:8080/appcontext/META-INF/index.html?

Tags: java, servlets

I have an example application that is running locally as `http://localhost:8080/appcontext` (the context is `/appcontext`).

Now when `http://localhost:8080/appcontext/META-INF/index.html` is accessed in a browser I want to display the text `Hello, World!`.

**Code for Servlet Mappings**

This is how I tried to map a Servlet to the `/META-INF` URL. But it didn't work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5"
>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.example.mapmetainf.MyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <!--
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/META-INF/index.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    -->

    <!--
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/META-INF/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    -->

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Servlet Specification**

Java Servlet Specification 3.1, Chapter SRV.9.6 Web Application Archive File:

> This directory must not be directly served as content by the container in response to a Web client’s request, [...]. Also, any requests to access the resources in META-INF
>   directory must be returned with a SC_NOT_FOUND(404) response.

This forbids the direct mapping of the `META-INF` directory of the .war. But I don't think it forbids mapping a Servlet to the `/appcontext/META-INF` URL.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Perhaps the problem lies deeper in what you are trying to do or there is an alternative.

Comment: No practical need. This is just for my education. If the Servlet specification defines a magic, unmappable URL, I'd like to know that ;-)

Comment: can you paste the code of how you tried to map it? maybe you are missing something, like escaping that "-"

Comment: If you know that serving files out of /META-INF is contrary to the Servlet Specification why do you want to do it?

Comment: @Gubatron edited question to include the web.xml

Comment: @EJP Tried to clarify my question. I don't want to serve files our of /META-INF. I want to use the URL /META-INF.

Comment: Now it's just confusing. Your new example where you try and use /context/META-INF contradicts with the rest of your question where you're trying to map /META-INF to a servlet.

Comment: It's in some way possible in Tomcat older than 6.0.30 and 7.0.4 due to a security bug (which was reported by me).

Comment: As first part of question was deemed too confusing. Removed and concentrated on example only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are asking is not possible at the application level. The specification talks only about the `META-INF` folder, but the URL is implied as well. I am using the term "implied" here because let's think for a minute the consequences of a server allowing you to do what you want.

If a server allowed the `/appcontext/META-INF` url to reach one of your filters/servlets then it has no way of knowing if you (the developer) would handle that case according to the specification or not. So strictly speaking, it does not fully conform to the specification. Even worse, it *relies on the web developer to do that*. If that was the case, then for every web application where the default behaviour was desired (i.e. `META-INF` to not be accessible), a developer would have to implement a servlet/filter to do something that the server should be doing in the first place (!)

So I believe that what you ask can only be available at a server level and only if the server allows you that i.e. if the server gives you a configuration option to do that, or allows you to write your own interceptor class to handle the request in a way different then the default behaviour.

In Tomcat 7 for example `META-INF` access is forbidden in the [StandardContextValve class](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-catalina/7.0.14/org/apache/catalina/core/StandardContextValve.java#StandardContextValve.invoke%28org.apache.catalina.connector.Request%2Corg.apache.catalina.connector.Response%29) in its `invoke()` method:

```
public final void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException, ServletException {

    // Disallow any direct access to resources under WEB-INF or META-INF
    MessageBytes requestPathMB = request.getRequestPathMB();
    if ((requestPathMB.startsWithIgnoreCase("/META-INF/", 0))
            || (requestPathMB.equalsIgnoreCase("/META-INF"))
            || (requestPathMB.startsWithIgnoreCase("/WEB-INF/", 0))
            || (requestPathMB.equalsIgnoreCase("/WEB-INF"))) {
            notFound(response);   // <-- Issues a response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
            return;
    }
    ...
}
```

So you would have to create your own `Valve` implementation (i.e. an `AllowMetaInfAccessValve` that would basically be a copy of the above class without that "disallow" check), package it in a jar and put it in the `<TOMCAT_HOME>/lib` folder.

Then in your `server.xml` you would declare something like below. Using that approach URLs that attempt to access the `META-INF` folder, would then reach your servlet and would be you own responsibility.

```
...
<Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
    ...
    <Valve className="com.mypackage.valves.AllowMetaInfAccessValve" allow="true"/>
    ...
</Host>
...
```

---

**Update:** To clarify my reasoning a little more: It is true that a servlet could do many things other than serving files from `META-INF` folder. But it could also do just that. Or even worse it would be sufficient for a web developer to just *forget to forbid access*, for the `META-INF` folder to become accessible.

The point here though is not what the servlet would or would not do. The point is: should the people that implemented the server depend on the web developer to conform to the specification? My guess is that they wouldn't feel too comfortable with that thought. A specification is basically a set of rules. If you want to be able to say "my server follows that set of rules" you cannot depend on what a third person would do. Put yourself in their shoes. What would you do? Would you depend on some developer or make sure that your server follows the rules?
I believe that most people would make the same decision i.e. by default forbid access and provide an extension point of some sort. Now if this is a good decision or a bad one, only time will tell. After all, specifications evolve too. I hope it is more clear now

Comment: That the spec implicitly disallows the appcontext/META-INF URL makes sense, thanks.
Although I don't completely follow your reasoning: There are many different things a Servlet mapped to appcontext/META-INF/* could do. Only a Servlet which serves resources from the META-INF folder directly would be in violation of the specification according to your reasoning.

Comment: @Arendv.Reinersdorff see the update in my answer. I have tried to clarify my reasoning a little more

Answer (score 1):

There are no restrictions on using "META-INF" as a context name (as far as I know, there are no restrictions on context names at all -- at least I can't find any looking through the [Servlet 3.0 spec](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/)).

The root path of the request will be /META-INF, which will be dispatched to the appropriate servlet context. The actual informational META-INF that cannot be accessed would be at the URL /META-INF/META-INF.

*Edit: Responding to your comment and question edits, although your question is still confusing:*

As for making /context/META-INF/abc.file say "Hello world" or whatever, you answered your own question already:

> Also, any requests to access the resources in META-INF directory must be returned with a SC_NOT_FOUND(404) response.

One thing you could do is add a custom 404 response that does what you want.

Comment: I'm trying to use /context/META-INF. Sorry this wasn't clear. Tried to clarify my question.

Comment: See edits, I think. Your question is very confusing now, though -- your Basic Example contradicts with the rest of the post where you are trying to map `/META-INF` to a servlet.

Comment: +1 for the custom 404 response. That works. Although it's quite a hack.

Comment: As for the spec, as I understand it "resources in META-INF directory" means the files in the .war. That should not prevent mapping a servlet to the /META-INF URL, should it?

Comment: Your whole question is quite a hack. I hope this is for educational purposes only. :)

Comment: You can map a servlet to /META-INF - i.e. "META-INF" is a valid context name. You keep juggling back and forth between /META-INF and /context/META-INF, it is becoming confusing.

Comment: You could create a ServletFilter that checks the URI for /context/META-INF and responds with something else, probably. It depends on whether or not the container actually passes requests for /context/META-INF to the dispatcher, or just responds with a 404 immediately

Comment: +1 for the ServletFilter idea. Doesn't work though. The filter is never called for a request to /context/META-INF. Not even when a custom 404 response is defined.

Answer (score 1):

`/META-INF/` and `/WEB-INF/` folders are special folders in a Java web applications. Under normal conditions no sane servlet container is going to let you access *anything* in these folders, as they usually contain very sensitive data which is not to be exposed to general public. If your app is deployed under `<context>` expect that `<context>/META-INF/*` and `<context>/WEB-INF/*` are inaccessible to anyone.

If possible, rely on another URL; I see no good reason for serving static or dynamic pages from `/META-INF/`.

If you do, however, really need to this URL to be exactly this, I would resolve to a trick and do set up an Apache web server in front of your application with [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html).

There you can say something like

```
RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/META-INF/(.*)$                          [NC]
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$          /metaInf/$0                               [P,L]
```

(Writting by hart, be sure to check exact syntax.) This will redirect all external requests for `/META-INF/` to your own's application `/metaInf/` folder and to the outside world it would seem that you are serving pages from `/META-INF/`.

But as said, again, not really something you'd want to do unless you have a very specific reason to do so.

Comment: Agreed. In practice a URL-rewrite outside of the Servlet application would probably the best solution.
Example use case: Nice URLs for books at Amazon:
http://www.amazon.de/Java-Puzzlers-Traps-Pitfalls-Corner/dp/032133678X/
Although I didn't find any books named META-INF or WEB-INF..

Answer (score -1):

**Servlet 3 compatible container**

Anything in a META-INF/resources directory in a JAR in WEB-INF/lib is automatically exposed as a static resource.

Comment: Sorry, it seems my question wasn't clear. I don't want to serve files our of /META-INF. I want to use the URL /META-INF